# How to use registered Hive UDF in Spark DataFrame?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have registered my hive UDF using the following code:

```
hiveContext.udf().register("MyUDF",new UDF1(String,String)) {
public String call(String o) throws Execption {
//bla bla
}
},DataTypes.String);
```

Now I want to use above MyUDF in `DataFrame`. How do we use it? I know how to use it in a SQL and it works fine

```
hiveContext.sql(select MyUDF("test") from myTable);
```

My `hiveContext.sql()` query involves group by on multiple columns so for scaling purpose I am trying to convert this query into DataFrame APIs

```
dataframe.select("col1","col2","coln").groupby(""col1","col2","coln").count();
```

Can we do the following: `dataframe.select(MyUDF("col1"))`?

Comment: You can only access UDFs via SQL, not via scala code.

Comment: @Reactormonk `callUDF` wouldn't work here?

Comment: @zero323 Yeah, forgot to theck the [functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$). They renamed it to `udf`.

Comment: @Reactormonk I thought about this one: `callUDF(udfName: String, cols: Column*): Column ` which is new in 1.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the following with pyspark 3.x running on top of yarn and it works

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df1 = df.withColumn("result", expr("MyUDF('test')"))
df1.show()
df2 = df.selectExpr("MyUDF('test') as result").show()
df2.show()
```

In case you come across Class not found error. Then you might want to add the jar using `spark.sql("ADD JAR hdfs://...")`